# Retrieve webclient response - Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webclient

I'm using spring cloud to request data from another service. So, basically I request data and I want to retrieve that data and assigns it to another object which will be the one I'll save.

This is my code:

```
public Mono<Shops> save(Shops shops) {

    Mono<Shops> s = webClientBuilder.build().get()
            .uri("http://mysql-app/api/reservation-passengers/boarding-pass-data/" + shops.getBoardingPassId().toString())
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> {
                Shops myShops = response.bodyToMono(Shops.class).block();
                shops.setAirportDestiny(myShops.getAirportDestiny());
                shops.setCustomerId(myShops.getCustomerId());
                return shopsRepository.save(shops);
            });
    return s;   
}
```

However I got an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-7
```

How can I get data from a asynchronous method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. I had to change my code a little bit.

```
public Mono<Shops> save(Shops shops) {
    Mono<BoardingPassDTO> response = webClientBuilder.build().get()
            .uri("http://mysql-app/api/reservation-passengers/boarding-pass-data/" 
                    + shops.getBoardingPassId().toString())
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(BoardingPassDTO.class);

    return response.flatMap(r ->{
            shops.setAirportDestiny(r.getAirportArrivalId());
            shops.setCustomerId(r.getPassengerId());    
            shops.setShopDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            return shopsRepository.save(shops);
        });     
}
```